# How can I solve this problem. React Router not updating routing on hosting

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have these codes below working smoothly on my local machine but was not working on hosting on netlify

Only the URL is changing but the page is not changing with the URL. This was not the case on my system.

This is the link on netlify https://adetoba-adedeji.netlify.app/#/

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import About from './components/About'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Projects from './components/Projects'
import Skills from './components/Skills'
import { Switch, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
    function Content() {
        const location = useLocation()
        const [displayLocation, setDisplayLocation] = useState(location)
        const [transitionStage, setTransistionStage] = useState('fadeIn')

        useEffect(() => {
            if (location !== displayLocation) setTransistionStage('fadeOut')
        }, [location])

        return (
            <div
                className={`animate-${transitionStage}`}
                onAnimationEnd={() => {
                    if (transitionStage === 'fadeOut') {
                        setTransistionStage('fadeIn')
                        setDisplayLocation(location)
                    }
                }}
            >
                <Switch location={displayLocation}>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={About} />
                    <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
                    <Route path='/skills' component={Skills} />
                    <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <main className='relative lg:h-screen font-mulish text-gray-400 bg-gray-900 body-font overflow-x-hidden'>
            <Navbar />
            <Content />
        </main>
    )
}

export default App
```

The index.js file is here below

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

The Navbar component is shown below. The other components using the `Link` follows the same pattern

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { ArrowRightIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import { ViewGridAddIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Modal from './Modal'

const Navbar = () => {

    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)
    
    const toggleModal = () => setModal(!modal)  

    return (
        <div className='relative z-20'>
            <header className='bg-gray-800 block fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 md:sticky md:top-0 z-20 shadow-box md:shadow-none md:border-0 rounded-t-xl md:rounded-none'>
                <div className='container mx-auto flex flex-wrap justify-between p-2 sm:p-3 md:p-4 flex-row items-center'>
                    <div className='title-font font-medium text-white'>
                        <span className='ml-3 font-medium text-sm md:text-xl'>
                            Adetoba Adedeji
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <nav className='hidden md:mr-auto md:ml-4 md:py-1 md:pl-4 md:border-l md:border-gray-700    md:flex flex-wrap items-center text-base justify-center'>
                        <Link to='/' className='mr-5 hover:text-white'>
                            About
                        </Link>
                        <Link to='/projects' className='mr-5 hover:text-white'>
                            Past Works
                        </Link>
                        <Link to='/skills' className='mr-5 hover:text-white'>
                            Skills
                        </Link>
                    </nav>
                    <Link
                        to='/contact'
                        className='hidden md:inline-flex items-center py-1 px-3 mt-1 sm:mt-0 rounded bg-green-500 border-0 focus:outline-none hover:bg-green-600 text-white text-base'
                    >
                        Hire Me
                        <ArrowRightIcon className='w-4 h-4 ml-1' />
                    </Link>
                    <div onClick={toggleModal} className=' md:hidden text-green-600'>
                        <ViewGridAddIcon className='w-8 h-8 ml-1' />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div
                className={` ${
                    modal ? 'block animate-modalIn' : 'hidden animate-modalOut'
                } block md:hidden fixed bottom-0 inset-x-0 w-full bg-gray-800 z-30 rounded-t-3xl`}
            >
                <Modal modal={modal} toggleModal={toggleModal} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a `Content` component ***inside*** another component, `App`? It looks like you've more than one router in your app. Can you provide all the relevant routing/navigation React code?

Comment: @DrewReese I have only one router in my App. The index.js is included now

Comment: Ah, I saw a couple `Router.Provider` components in the tree, but you may be correct. Feel free to ping me when you add all the relevant routing/navigation code to your question. In other words, the relevant code between that `HashRouter` and any `Link` components that are triggering navigation. I'll check back again later.

Comment: @DrewReese I added the Navbar codes too. Other components using `Link` follows the same pattern as the Navbar

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you may change your `HashRouter` with `BrowserRouter` then you import as `Router`.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```